# JQuery - converting JS to JQuery for generating table that allows parsing URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have a problem with transforming my vanilla JS code to JQuery. I need to take parameter values from URL.
For example:

> localhost:63342/2018-11-13-html/form_sent.html?phone=4325325235&adress=testadress&order=book1&order=book2&deliverydate=datadostawy&deliverymethod=chinamail&agree=on

My current attempt is producing [Object object] in place of the values it's supposed to be throwing out.

```
function createSimpleRow(header, value) {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    return $("<tr></tr>").append($("<th></th>").text(header)).append($("<td></td>").text(`${urlParams.getAll(value)}`));
}

function readBookOrder(booklist) {
    const list = document.getElementById(booklist);
    const table = document.createElement("table");


    table.append(createSimpleRow("phone", `phone`));
    table.append(createSimpleRow("adress", `adress`));

    list.appendChild(table);
    return list;
}
```

My old code is a mix of Jquery and pure JS and it seems to be working correctly, giving out all the values I've specified to take from the URL.

```
function readBookOrder(booklist) {
    const list = document.getElementById(booklist);
    const table = document.createElement("table");

     const tr = document.createElement("tr");
     const td1 = document.createElement("td");
     td1.innerHTML = `${urlParams.get("phone")}`;
     tr.appendChild(td1);
     const td2 = document.createElement("td");
     td2.innerHTML = `${urlParams.get("adress")}`;
     tr.appendChild(td2);
     const td3 = document.createElement("td");
     td3.innerHTML = `${urlParams.getAll("order")}`;
     tr.appendChild(td3);
     const td4 = document.createElement("td");
     td4.innerHTML = `${urlParams.get("deliverydate")}`;
     tr.appendChild(td4);
     const td5 = document.createElement("td");
     td5.innerHTML = `${urlParams.get("deliverymethod")}`;
     tr.appendChild(td5);

    table.appendChild(tr);
    list.appendChild(table);
    return list;
}
```

Can someone suggest what is that I'm missing out during the convertion to the JQuery standard?

Comment: Because `createSimpleRow()` returns an jQuery context (which is basically on `Object` that encapsulates the nodes you created) that you're trying to `append()` to a native element. Try to append `[0]` at the end of your `return` statement to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `createSimpleRow()` now returns a `jQuery` object you can't append that object directly with native DOM methods.

Convert `readBookOrder()` to use `jQuery` methods instead that allow for inserting other jQuery objects

```
function readBookOrder(booklist) {
    const $list = $(`#${booklist}`);
    const $table = $("<table>");

    ['phone', 'adress'].forEach(e => $table.append(createSimpleRow(e, e)) );       

    $list.append($table);
    return $list;
}
```

The convention of adding a `$` prefix to variable names is a common one to reflect that the variable contains a jQuery object

Comment: Thank you! Now I see why so many methods weren't working. Guess I have to learn quite a lot.